# WebStorm (PhpStorm, IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm) issue with Git

Tags: git, webstorm

I want to see files that were changed in Version Control Log, but I'm seeing just some description about commit. It was okay before.

How to change that setting?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might have accidentally resized the detail pane so that it covers the list of files. Try dragging down to reveal the file list like this:

[image: dragging down to reveal files in the selected commit]

Comment: If for some reasons resizing the panel does not work, it is possible to reset its size in the config file. See e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208353545-Changed-files-pane-in-Log-tab-of-Version-Control-tool-not-showing